# Sent Eth to contract address can I get it back

Tags: ether, contract-design, etherscan, contract-debugging

I sent some Eth to a contract address rather than my wallet. Can someone with some code experience have a look at this contract and let me know if there is a function on here that the Devs could use to send it back to me

Here is the token contract https://etherscan.io/address/0xE453C3409f8Ad2B1FE1ED08E189634d359705A5B#code

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ETH can be withdrawn to your wallet address by the [owner of the contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x3cCc502154730EF49d83762bd7aE742F4ae80B32) using the [withdrawETH](https://etherscan.io/address/0xE453C3409f8Ad2B1FE1ED08E189634d359705A5B#writeContract#F15) function.

You can try messaging to the owner address using the [Blockscan Chat](https://chat.blockscan.com/index?a=0x3cCc502154730EF49d83762bd7aE742F4ae80B32). Or, you can also try reaching out to their socials as mentioned on their [website](https://www.dgi.game/), regarding the same.

Comment: Which file is that in? I have reached out to them was just trying to be a bit proactive for when they reply